# Make a Heroku site redirect to another Heroku site

Tags: heroku

Let's say I have a heroku site at http://website.herokuapp.com and I want to redirect its visitors to my other heroku site at http://another_website.herokuapp.com. Is there any way to do this without touching the code of either site (just from the heroku dashboard or terminal)?

I have an old heroku rails site that I want to keep as is, and I don't know where its code is. But I want to redirect its visitors to my new heroku site just for this month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to setup a redirect directly in Heroku. What you can do is either configure the redirect at your registrar (if you use a custom domain, some registrars offer a redirect feature), update your app or point the source of the redirect to another app and deploy a simple redirect code.